# Conflicting changes cannot be committed?

Tags: java, eclipse, synchronization, repository

when I want to commit to my respository I get the message:

> Conflicting changes cannot be committed. Either exclude them from the
>   commit or use the synchronize view to resolve the conflicts

There is also a little problem with syncronizing: I always get a red mark when I synchronize?

Can you help me?

Comment: Which (D)VCS are you using? CVS? Do you understand what a "conflict" is?

Comment: It's not an automatic process.  You actually have to look at both versions of the code and talk to the other developer to work out the conflicts.

Comment: I guess a conflict is when I cannot "purchase" a file...;?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update (and merge changes == resolve conflicts) first, then you can commit.

Comment: thx it worked. So to summarys: An update is that eclipse gets all files from the repo and a syncronization is when i just gets the files that I already have on my PC. Right????

Comment: Update - when client (eclipse or any other) gets updated source from server. Sync is update and commit in that order. Again automatic commit will happen only if there are no conflicts.